# Why do I get the error `kafka.Client` is not a constructor, meanwhile on `npm kafka-node` this is the way to create a Kafka connection?

Tags: rest, express, apache-kafka, kafka-node

Why do I get the error `kafka.Client` is not a constructor, meanwhile on `npm kafka-node` this is the way to create a kafka connection?

The specific problematic line is: `this.client = new kafka.Client();`
The entire constructor is:

```
constructor(){
    this.Producer = kafka.Producer,
    this.client = new kafka.Client();
    this.producer = new Producer(client);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem was the following. With this implementation the code was working as expected:

```
    constructor(){
        this.Producer = kafka.Producer,
        this.client = new kafka.KafkaClient();
        this.producer = new kafka.Producer(this.client);
}
```